# How to create installer for ASP.NET MVC 4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, installation

I have created a mobile web application in ASP.NET MVC 4 using Visual Studio 2012.

I have created deployment options to deploy the web app to our own servers but now I need to create an installer for the web application so it can be installed on customer servers.

I was looking for an option to create such an installer in VS2012 but I don't see one.

The only setup and deployment project type I see in VS2012 is InstallShield and it is geared for windows applications, not web applications.

So, how are web application installers supposed to be made in VS2012?

Comment: You can use Wix (windows installer toolkit) to create installers that will work for websites.  However wix sucks (sorry, Rob, but it really does).  If you're working for a company, go buy an installer product that can work with websites.

Comment: If you don't like WiX, because of the scripting, another option is Advanced Installer,advancedinstaller.com, (I work on the company building it). It has an extension for VS 2010 and 2012, and in the next version will also have for 2013. Here is the IIS support that you can find in it: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-iis.html

Answer (score 0):

VS2012 does not have straight forward way to load VS2012 installer projects (*.vdproj)

Try downloading VS 2015 and then you need to install package for "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects" https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9
Bingo